# Create Insert Record for Master and Child Data

Tags: oracle-adf

Hi I've a Employee and Dept Table EO and VO created with ViewLink. Now I've a API that I will be calling to save this record.

I've created a jsff and when I drag the Employee instance in jsff as ADF Form and Run it, it create the Label without the InputText. Later I used createinsert but if I dray the Empoyee CreateInsert it only displays the Input text for Empoyee attributes and If I use the createinsert of dept the dept attributes input text is visible.

1) What is the way in which I can make both employee and dept inputtext visible?

2) As I will be accessing this VO's in my java code and process them to call the API for insert, is it recommended to uses CreateInsert operation? If not whats the best way?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ADFS - removed tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two createInsert operations into a single button:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/doing_two_declarative_operatio